# How do I call a program or code which has main in debug mode?

Tags: c++, debugging, debug-mode

I have a CPP program (let's call it program 1) which calls another CPP program (Program 2). This Program2 is built in debug mode. That is:

```
   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ///Function body#
     eerot[0] = atof(argv[1]); 
eerot[1] = atof(argv[2]); 
eerot[2] = atof(argv[3]); 
eetrans[0] = atof(argv[4]); //Exception thrown here due to memory clash
     ///Continue
    }
```

The above fragment of the code describes the structure of my main program in program2. Program2 has neither execution error nor does it throw any exception. Now I want to call this main function of program2 from program1 but I am stuck with the double pointer variable. Because the argv variable is double pointer, and even though I was able to create a string, double reference it and pass it as parameter to program2, I get exceptions. There is no compile error. All the appropriate headers are perfectly defined.

I cannot edit program2 since it was developed by some other team and it is quite difficult to follow. I have changed the name of main function of program 2(say to "calculate()") and called that from main of program1. I have also included directories and header files appropriately to make all functions and classes of program2 visible in program1. Right now only thing I am stuck is with the double pointer argv variable. How can I pass the parameters which I have to pass via the command prompt be passed via another program?

Note that the parameters we pass in command prompt for program2 is of type double. I tried to use arrays but I keep getting exceptions thrown at me. Let me know anything that comes to your mind when trying to solve the problem.

Comment: what exceptions are thrown at you? did you try to catch them?

Comment: Not exactly. It will run even if I choose different lines for each end of line semicolon.

Comment: sorry for my bad wording. What I wanted to say is: please do not put everything on the same line, it just makes it harder to read

Comment: what is `eerot` and `eetrans` ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I made a mistake there. I will remove it

Comment: This: `int main(int argc, char** argv[])` makes *no* sense. Did you mean `int main(int argc, char** argv)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` ?

Comment: @eerot and eetrans and just variable to get data from the pointer variable argv

Comment: Please read about [mcve] and try to provide one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the triple pointer in the main() declaration.  You probably meant:

`int main(int argc, char** argv) {`

or

`int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {`

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I made a typo there. I changed it. However my problem is still there

Comment: @prashanthkumar argv[0] is the invoked program name. argv[1] is the first parameter. What happens if you run the program with an extra parameter or two? If no exception, that would strongly hint at a mistake in the indexes of the parameters used.

Answer (score 0):

you want either char **argv ... OR char *argv[], NOT char **argv[]

both of the above are pointers to arrays. What you have is a pointer to a 2D array basically so the way you are accessing the elements ends up exceeding the number of array elements.

Comment: Sorry about that. I made a typo there. But my problem persists even if I just use **argv or *argv[]

Comment: argc will be the number of strings entered through command line arguments, maybe add some error checking so you never access argv[argc] or higher?